# How to store and update user data in firebase with js (web)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a simple web app that has a login system and adds score to the user signed in and that score is saved in the Firebase database. I've got the authentication part working but very confused with storing , updating and retrieving the user data :( . I'd want a similar behavior :

**My database could look / store stuffs like this :**

Users:

1. abc@gmail.com

   - score : 12
2. cde@gmail.com

   - score : 34

and so on .

My code for adding the user to the database :

```
 let userRef = firebase.database.ref("users/" + userId);

 userRef.child("mike").set({ score: 12 });
```

But I get this error : ReferenceError: userId is not defined , followed this guide https://medium.com/@hasangi/writing-deleting-and-updating-data-in-firebase-realtime-database-with-javascript-f26113ec8c93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the data inside Realtime Database ([Official Realtime Database Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write))

```js
firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`)
  .set({
     score: `${scoreYouWantToSet}`,
  });
```

If you want to store the data inside Firestore ([Official Firestore Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data))

```js
firebase.firestore().collection(`users/${userId}`).add({
  score: `${scoreYouWantToSet}`
})
```

Comment: No problem. You could ping me anytime.